# How to publish gradle sub projects?

Tags: gradle

I have a newly created Gradle project with 2 sub projects. I need to publish artifacts to a nexus repository. Hence i have used gradle publish plugin inside subprojects as following code sample in `build.gradle` file.

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group project.group

subprojects {
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId project.group
                artifactId project.name
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url project.url
                credentials {
                    username project.sonatypeUsername
                    password project.sonatypePassword
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then included sub projects `settings.gradle` file as follows.

```
include 'sub-proj-1'
include 'sub-proj-2'
```

Here when publishing it iterates root project and 2 sub projects but publish all artifacts under `sub-proj-2` artifact name.

If i do a `println project.name` it will print all the sub project names and do the publishing to the last sub project.

Even i tried `afterEvaluate` as following, it published all the artifacts under root project.

```
mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
    groupId project.group
    afterEvaluate {
        artifactId project.name
    }
}
```

I have included the test project of above code snippets in a [Github repository](https://github.com/keizer619/test-project)

Comment: It looks like in your real project (not in the sample Git repo, where the problem is not reproductible) you have configured the sub-project's `build.gradle` script using `subprojects` closure, as written in your question, which can explain the behavior you described:   when Gradle will configure sub-project `sub-proj-2`, it will apply the `publishing` configuration to all sub-projects ; this is why sub-project `sub-proj-1` inherits publishing information from the other sub-project.